# Lighttpd x.example.com to example.com/x

Tags: lighttpd

I'd like to configure my lighttpd setup so that when you visit `*.example.com` it serves you with the contents `example.com/*`, but the URL stil shows `*.example.com`. 
How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite) would be the appropriate tool, it changes where the request goes to with out changing what the user sees in the url.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)\.example.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^/$" => "/%1" )
}
```

The above code matches for hosts beginning in anything and ending in .example.com. The rewrite rule inside rewrites the url from / to /, %(number) matches the exterior regex subpatterns, $(number) would be any subpattern inside the url.rewrite-once.

*Disclaimer: I'm getting some funny behaviour, a 301 redirect, which I suspect is coming from some of the other config I have in play, url.rewrite shouldn't cause any redirects.

Comment: For a (to me) unknown reason, it doesn't work. The website isn't found

Comment: 404 error, or DNS lookup failed? I figured out that the redirect behaviour I was seeing had to do with directory listings. It might help to add `mod_accesslog` to server modules and something like `accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"` to put the file somewhere, and see what requests lighttpd is seeing.

Comment: You didn't really answer 404 or DNS, but if it is DNS, do you have wildcards enabled? If you access anything else, something already existing, does the access log show anything? It should if it is setup and working right.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I was trying through a DDNS, which had subdomains disabled. Thanks for your help

Comment: Since this was probably the correct answer, I'm going to go ahead and set it as my accepted answer.